# the friend class point to a class of the same name in a different namespace

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen3

I'm sorry I cannot describe the problem clearly.
The error given by the compiler is:

```
D:\download\tensorflow-master\tensorflow-master\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf\src\protobuf\src\google/protobuf/arena.h(883): error C3855: “Eigen::Map”: type parameter 'MapOption' is incompatible with the declaration
D:\download\tensorflow-master\tensorflow-master\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf\src\protobuf\src\google/protobuf/arena.h(883): error C2976: “Eigen::Map”: too few type arguments
```

The error comes from the official tensorflow code, and I could run the example program written in C++. While when I try to insert my tensorflow code into my another project, here comes the error.

```
 template <typename Key, typename T>
 friend class Map;
```

I know the problem is that the 'Map' point to the Eigen::Map while it needs to point to the google::protobuff::Map. Additionally, the declaration of 'Map' is under the google::protobuff namespace. 
Did anyone meet the same problem before?
I'm trying my best to give a clear statement. Thanks a lot！

Comment: We can't really tell you anything from this, please include your error in English, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: At a guess do you have `using namespace Eigen` either in your header files or in your cpp files before one of your includes?

Comment: Then use fully qualified names, either `Eigen::Map` or `google::protobuff::Map`and forget `using namespace` constructs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why you should not:

1. Use `using namespace` within scope with declarations
2. Rely on redefinition of identifiers reserved or used in standard or common libraries

Both cause conflicts of names and latter able to cause a nundetectable conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！And I fix the problem by delete  the 'using namespace'. However, new problems occur because of the macro conflict between opencv and tensorflow, How could I fix this problem (I'm not allowed to modify the official code)

Comment: @BLACK depends on type of conflict.. if that's conflict between enum and macro, then order of headers might help. If that conflict of macro-definitions with same name and different content.. I guess, that's reason to use separate compilation units

Comment: Independent of the cause, that is a separate issue, which requires a new question, with a new [mcve].